# How do I solve the Type error: Cannot find name 'Query' in Next.js project

Tags: typescript, graphql, next.js

I'm already struggling a while to solve this error and would appreciate any feedback since the error is breaking the production deployments :)

The project is a Next.js typescript project with graphql integration to the backend. The `graphql-codegen` is used for generation of the `graphql.d.tsx` file which contains the following code:

```
export function useQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<Query, QueryVariables>) {
        return Apollo.useQuery<Query, QueryVariables>(Document, baseOptions);
      }
export function useLazyQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.LazyQueryHookOptions<Query, QueryVariables>) {
          return Apollo.useLazyQuery<Query, QueryVariables>(Document, baseOptions);
        }
export type QueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useQuery>;
export type LazyQueryHookResult = ReturnType<typeof useLazyQuery>;
export type QueryResult = Apollo.QueryResult<Query, QueryVariables>;
```

In case I run the project in dev mode there is no error and functionalities are working as expected. The moment I want to run `npx next build` I receive the error:

```
./src/generated/graphql.d.tsx:8390:64
Type error: Cannot find name 'Query'.

  8388 |  * });
  8389 |  */
> 8390 | export function useQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<Query, QueryVariables>) {
       |                                                                ^
  8391 |         return Apollo.useQuery<Query, QueryVariables>(Document, baseOptions);
```

So my question is: How to solve this? And if more information is required please let me know.

Thanks

**Update 1:**
As requested the `codegen.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    schema: [
        {
            endpoint_location: {
                headers: {
                    //Authorization: 'Bearer ' + process.env.AUTH_TOKEN,
                    "x-hasura-admin-secret": secretKey,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    documents: ['./gpl/**/*.graphql'],
    overwrite: true,
    generates: {
        './src/generated/graphql.d.tsx': {
            plugins: [
                'typescript',
                'typescript-operations',
                'typescript-react-apollo',
            ],
            config: {
                skipTypename: false,
                withHooks: true,
                withHOC: false,
                withComponent: false,
                noExport: true,
                apolloReactHooksImportFrom: "@apollo/client"
            },
        },
        './graphql.schema.json': {
            plugins: ['introspection'],
        },
    },
};
```

**Update 2:**
Checked the file `graphql.scheme.json` and found the following code:

```
{
            "name": "queryType",
            "description": "The type that query operations will be rooted at.",
            "args": [],
            "type": {
              "kind": "NON_NULL",
              "name": null,
              "ofType": {
                "kind": "OBJECT",
                "name": "__Type",
                "ofType": null
              }
            },
            "isDeprecated": false,
            "deprecationReason": null
          },
```

And the graphql file we have defined as query is defined as:

```
query getWordsByColor{
  mainColorsWords{
    word
    mainColor {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're missing `type Query`, its somewhere or not generated at all

Comment: Thanks for your swift support but do you know how to add this and my expectation is that all required components should be generated by the codegen (?). Thanks

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your codegen config file.

Comment: Also, have you actually defined a Query type inside your schema?

Comment: The issue has been updated with requested information.